# using @font-face

Tags: html, css, font-face

Im trying to use a custom font  using @font-face and for some reason its working on some places and not in others.

**CSS**
This works fine

```
#hero-header .title {
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 225px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Populaire';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 64px;
    }
```

This doesn't

```
ul#reviews h2 {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Populaire';
    }
```

Notice the Hero area using a custom font but unable to use it further down the page, ie: the review titles.

Comment: anyway: your page does not validate: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oatbook.co.uk%2Fbeta%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on the font...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Populaire';
    src: url('font/Populaire.otf');
}
```

But, the font is actually in `/beta/styles/css/fonts/Populaire.otf`, please update your CSS to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Populaire';
    src: url('/beta/styles/css/fonts/Populaire.otf');
}
```

Comment: Been looking at it for too long, knew it would be something as minimal as that :) Thanks for your help